# What is the immigration process when leaving the Philippines?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, philippines

I am a first time traveler and I've been refused boarding on a flight to India due to lack of needed documents. Now I have the documents from my sponsor in India. He bought me a ticket on MakeMyTrip. From the Philippines, I will go via Singapore to fly to India. What is the process? Will Philippines Immigration ask me lot of questions?

Comment: Boyfriend you've never met = that is not normal. Real people do not do that. Real people want to *meet* their partners, and do *other things* with their partners, heh heh.  If he's the wealthier one, **he'd have come to you already**.  SCAM. This guy probably has 50 "girlfriends" on the dangle, and keeps paperwork on each one so he doesn't mix up your details. Most likely, what awaits you is "being trafficked", for a girl, unimaginable horror.

Answer (score 7):

First, you must be sure that your sponsor is legitimate. The Philippine government put that process in place because a lot of pinoys have been tricked into slavery or prostitution in foreign countries by sponsors who appear to be trustworthy.

If your sponsor is someone you know well and who has visited you in Philippines, then you should know enough about them and about your trip to be able to answer questions that immigration staff ask you. Even then, there is a risk that this is a scam.

Allow plenty of time at the airport so you don't miss your flight.

Comment: thank you for your response, My sponsor is my BF we are in relationship for 3 years and we haven't meet yet since he is so busy at work. However he send me a notarize invitation letter, Indian ID , Passport bank statements. All is stamped by their Govt. Would this be enough documents to convince immigration and less chance for me to be offloaded again?.

Comment: Sorry but that sounds like a scam. There are people who put a lot of work into being convincing boyfriends but really just plan to exploit you. The reason I think it's a scam is that if he can't find a few days to visit you in the Philippines when you've been together _3 years_ then telling you he's busy with work is just an excuse.

Comment: @MariedithEstrada Those documents do prove your bf's existence, but not scam vs genuine relationship. Even if he is busy, you should be important enough for him to make the time to visit you on your home ground, where you have family and/or friends. That would be much safer for you, especially if you have no experience of international travel.

Comment: Also, during a visit in the Philippines you could generate documentation, such as photos of you and your bf together, that would help with the exit interview.